# How to find out what letter is not in the font?

Tags: java, fonts, itext, itext7

If I do this:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(font_without_a, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
System.out.println("font_without_a " + font.getWidth("a",17));
```

> Output: font_without_a 5.848

The font does not have the letter "a"

font:
[image]

> https://dropmefiles.com/8lFiM

With the letter a, this is an example, can be any character

Comment: *The font does not have the letter "a"* - what does that mean? It doesn't have a glyph that looks like 'a'? Or it doesn't have a glyph mapped to by the character code for 'a'? You probably should share your font font_without_a.

Comment: I totally agree with @mkl, the question is unclear at the moment, `font.getWidth` gives you the width of the glyph `a` and because it gave you the width it definitely means that the font contains this letter. So please clarify how do you detect that `a` is missing

Comment: I understand that even if there is no letter, there is an empty area with borders, but can it be possible to somehow define this area as empty or not?

Comment: Ah, allright, now your question is clear. Unfortunately, iText does not have this possibility because iText does not parse glyph instructions. This is a problem with font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to find out what letter is not in the font?

You can check whether a font has a glyph for a given character using the `containsGlyph` method. This method does not try to determine, though, whether or not the drawing instructions for that glyph in the font somehow correlate with the character in question.

The font program ArtScript.ttf you shared *does* contain a glyph for the letter 'a', even though this glyph is void of drawing instructions. Thus, `PdfFont` correctly outputs `true` when asked

```
System.out.println(font.containsGlyph('a'));
```

I actually removed that glyph from your font program [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext7/font/ArtScript-a-removed.ttf). For this font that line of code outputs `false`.

In a comment you said

> I understand that even if there is no letter, there is an empty area with borders, but can it be possible to somehow define this area as empty or not?

Using a font editor you can actually remove the glyph, e.g. in FontForge using "cut" or "detach and remove glyphs" as I did above.